# Json having "-" in key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var data = {
    "train": {
        "number": "12155",
        "days": [
            {
                "runs": "Y",
                "day-code": "SUN"
            },
            {
                "runs": "Y",
                "day-code": "MON"
            },
            {
                "runs": "Y",
                "day-code": "TUE"
            },
            {
                "runs": "Y",
                "day-code": "WED"
            },
            {
                "runs": "Y",
                "day-code": "THU"
            },
            {
                "runs": "Y",
                "day-code": "FRI"
            },
            {
                "runs": "Y",
                "day-code": "SAT"
            }
        ],
        "name": "BHOPAL  EXPRESS"
    },
    "response_code": 200
};
$(document).ready(function(){

var datalist = data.train.days;


      for(var i in datalist)
      {
           $(".train").append("<p> Run on" +datalist[i].day-code +"-" + datalist[i].runs +"</p>");
      }


});
```

This code give me a error `datalist[i].day-code` "code is not define".How i can access a key which contains "-" .As it is running fine if am only using `datalist[i].runs`.Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
datalist[i].day-code
```

with

```
datalist[i]['day-code']
```

Comment: its ok and I voted for you

Comment: It also give me error "unexpected token  ["

Comment: wouldn't `datalist[i].dayCode` work as well?

Comment: @SatnamSingh - Initially there was an error in answer with a `.` prior to bracket. Please try updated answer

Comment: @CodeiSir: I sure hope not. (No, that won't work.)

Comment: `var datalist = data.train.days;for (var i in datalist) { $(".train").append("<p> Run on" + datalist[i]["day-code"] + "-" + datalist[i].runs + "</p>"); }`